# Random image link php

Tags: php, wordpress, random, while-loop

I am trying to put a Random Image on the top of the post, If I do the following code it shows all three images and link which is aspected. see it in here [PALEOALL](http://paleoall.com).

How could I randomise it to show just it one of then at time randomly with the php while command is running?

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

                <a href="http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/" title="Your Guide to Paleo"><img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/1.jpg" width="468" height="60" alt="Your Guide to Paleo" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" /></a>

                <a href="http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/" title="Your Guide to Paleo"><img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/2.jpg" width="468" height="60" alt="Your Guide to Paleo" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" /></a>

                <a href="http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/" title="Your Guide to Paleo"><img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/3.jpg" width="468" height="60" alt="Your Guide to Paleo" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" /></a>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I tried this but is not working with the while.

```
<?php
$images = array(
    array("src" => "img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/1.jpg", "url" => "http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/"),
    array("src" => "img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/2.jpg", "url" => "http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/"),  
    array("src" => "img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/3.jpg", "url" => "http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/"),
    array("src" => "img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/4.jpg", "url" => "http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/"),  
    array("src" => "img src="http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/5.jpg", "url" => "http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/")
); 

shuffle($images);

echo '<div class="images">';

foreach ($images as $image) {

    echo '<a href="'.$image["url"].'"><img src="'.$image["src"].'" /></a>';

}

echo '</div>';
```

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: So you need to show all of the shuffled or you need to display just one random image? Do you have any caching plugin enabled in your WordPress?

Comment: The command Albzi sent have worked, but it showing the same image on the top of every post, but once you refresh that image changes.

Comment: it is good already, but would be perfect to have it shuffling diferent images on the top of each post.

Comment: I dont have any caching Plugin installed, why? Should I have it?

Comment: No. The reason I asked is that if you had one, WP might be producing the same cached output every time, not re-generating on every request.

Comment: I see, Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$img = 'http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/'.mt_rand(1, 5).'.jpg';
```

Then you would do:

```
<img src='<?php echo $img; ?>'>
```

`mt_rand(x, y)` will get you a number between `x` and `y`, in this example it will be `1` and `5`.

If you want it to be random for every post, do this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    ?>

    $img = 'http://paleorecipebook.com/yourguidetopaleo-affiliates/468x60/'.mt_rand(1, 5).'.jpg';

    <a href="http://huander.yourpaleo.hop.clickbank.net/" title="Your Guide to Paleo"><img src="<?php echo $img;?>" width="468" height="60" alt="Your Guide to Paleo" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" /></a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: If you check the site again you will see that it worked. http://www.paleoall.com/

Comment: Is there a way to randomize it for each post?

Comment: I guess it could work, but this is very 'url name' dependant heavy. You can not do anything if for exemple there is no number "5" image but instead, 6.

Comment: This is true @Enjoyted, I just worked off what he gave us. Obviously your method would be better for different URL's, but this works for what OP has asked for :)

Comment: @Albzi the code worked, there is one image that doenst load, do you thing if I start it from `0` instead of `1` it will work?

Comment: I just looked and it turns out `5` doesn't exist. Change `mt_rand(1,5)` to `mt_rand(1,4)` @Huander

Comment: Thank you @albzi You are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken, you want, with `n` number of given images, show one of them randomly.

altough Albzi's answers could work in a way, where your images all end with an incrementing number, I don't think that's the good way of approaching it.

I would do =

```
$array = array(
   0 => array('src' => 'img747148.jpg'), // 0
   1 => array('src' => 'img74787778.jpg'), // 1
   2 => array('src' => 'img7486878.jpg'), // 2
   3 => array('src' => 'img747458.jpg') // 3
);

$randomNumber = rand(0, count($array)-1); // gives 2 for exemple
$image = $array[$randomNumber];
var_dump($image); // array('src' => 'src3.com', 'url' =>  'img7486878.jpg');
```

this way your images urls can be named of you please to. It will really get a random image between any given image, according you respect the indexes in the array.

Comment: Enjoyted, thank you for your answer, but it didnt work for me.

Comment: you probably didn't set it up correctly. What errors did you get ?

Comment: I have added the code you've sent on my function.php and just entered the img link which is an url adress, once saved my site crashed. possibly i am not putting it on the right place. @enjoyted

Comment: A site just doesn't crash ! Don't you get any errors? Also, make sure you place $image['src'] inside the src tag of your image. I updated the array to be much simpler.

Comment: yes you are correct the site did not crash, I am at work and they dont allow FTP connection, i am  doing it through the wordpress editor. once the code have a problem the site just goes blank. I dont know how to troubleshoot for error.